# Creating a VBA SUMX2MY2 Function Equivalent

Tags: vba, function, basic

I am attempting to practice my VBA skills by coding the equivalent of SUMX2MY2 in my own function, mySUMX2MY2 (I realize I could use =SUMPRODUCT but I'm practicing functions). I'm trying to do it by creating two arrays from whatever ranges are selected and squaring the ranges and minus the second squared range. Each time I try in excel, I get the error #VALUE. My guess is the error is with the argument my function is returning but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
Sub main()


End Sub

 Function mySumX2MY2(n1 As Range, n2 As Range) As Variant 

 Dim n1Array() As Variant
 Dim n2Array() As Variant
 Dim total As Variant
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim aCell As Variant
 
 i = 1
 
 ReDim n1Array(n1.Count)
 ReDim n2Array(n2.Count)

For Each aCell In n1
   n1Array(i) = aCell.Value
   i = i + 1
Next

For Each aCell In n2
   n2Array(i) = aCell.Value
   i = i + 1
Next

i = 1

For i = 1 To n1.Rows.Count
    total = total + (n1Array(i) * n1Array(i) - n2Array(i) * n2Array(i))
    i = i + 1
Next

mySumX2MY2 = total

End Function
```

Comment: You don't reset `i` after the first loop.   And you can read a range directly into an array eg. `myArray = n1.Value`

Comment: The best approach to debugging a user-defined function is to call it from a Sub.